# Strtotime Function

Tags: php, function, unix-timestamp

I made a script where I put all date informations: day, month, year , hour , minutes and format like AM or PM.
Then I take all informations with:

`$day = $_POST['day']`

`..........`

That's how I take all informations and it works well, but when I wanna do:

`$time = strtotime($hour.':'.$minute.' '.$format.' '.$year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day);`

It updates my database with UTC from 1970, actualy first second ever count.

What is wrong?

Comment: change format ... strtotime(Y-m-d h:i)

Answer (score 2):

The `H:i A Y-m-d` [is not an acceptable format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) for `strtotime()`. You need to use `Y-m-d H:i A`.

```
$time = strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day.' '.$hour.':'.$minute.' '.$format);
```

Comment: No... This still doesn't works... Thank you for atention

Comment: Then you need to show the values for your variables as this will work

Comment: Actualy, i see, this script doesn't works with more variabiles... If i have only 2, like date ( 1 Jan 2015) and 1 like hour (12:00 PM), works fine... Should i stick them ?

Comment: I have 6 `<select></select>` : 1 - days (1-31), 2-month (1-12), 3-year(2015 - 2020), 4-hour(1-12), 5-minutes(0-59), 6-format(AM or PM). All i want is to make `$time = strtotime(from all variables)` but, instead, i get 0 ... I don't know why ... Do you understand now ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, strtotime works fine now with this format:

```
  $time = strtotime($day.'-'.$month.'-'.$year.' '.$hour.':'.$minute.' '.$format);
```

That's the correct version !